# Create JSON Object multiple calls Angular 2 RXJS

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, rxjs

I´m a little bit confused about this, but here I go:

I have information about two characters, which I get from multiple endpoints. This information is just single data that is not organised from the backend, so instead of receiving something like this:

```
character{
    character1{
        name: "Name of Character",
        age: "21",
        jobs: {
                job1: {
                    position:
                    company:
                },
                job2: {
                    position:
                    company;
                }
        }
    },
    character2{
        name: "Name of Character",
        age: "21",
        jobs: {
                job1: {
                    position:
                    company:
                },
                job2: {
                    position:
                    company;
                }
        }
    }   
}
```

I receive character name from one endpoint, character age in another and so on, for example:

```
.../Characters/Character_1
../Characters/Character_1/age
../Characters/Character_1/name
../Characters/Character_1/job1
../Characters/Character_1/job1/position
../Characters/Character_1/job1/company
```

..and separated endpoints for character 2...

```
../Characters/Character_2
../Characters/Character_2/age
../Characters/Character_2/name
...
```

From my point of view, this organisation process should be done from the backend, but sadly it is not, and that´s the way I have to collect the data.

I must not only displaying information, but sometimes I also have to count how many jobs a character has.

> REMOVED FIRST EXAMPLES AS THEY WON´T WORK

---

STEP 1

So, as suggested I started to use forkJoin

with .../Characters/ I get the number of characters. This endpoint contains a list of endpoints urls where I need to return only those that include the word Character in theirs URL.

Note: All Endpoints return information in the next format:

```
{"children":["../pathOfCurrentEndpoint/path_1","../pathOfCurrentEndpoint/path_2","../pathOfCurrentEndpoint/path_3","../pathOfCurrentEndpoint/path_4"],"path":"../pathOfCurrentEndpoint","type":"Folder"}
```

//Component

```
  public characterVariable: any;

  constructor(private _service: Service) {    
    this.getCharacters();
  }

  getCharacters() {
    this._service.getAllCharacters().subscribe(
      characters => { this.characterVariable = characters;
        console.log("Json Object", this.characterVariable);
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
```

//Service

```
    /**
   * This method obtains the number of characters and all the data from each one of them
   * @returns {Array} Observable array witth each Character data
   */
  getAllCharacters(): Observable<String[]> {

    let url = '../Characters';
    let subString = 'Character';
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(this.extractPath)
      .map(data => data.filter(data => data.includes(subString)))
      //Send the two founded characters URL
      .concatMap((data) => this.getCharactersEndpoints(data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getCharactersEndpoints(data): Observable<String[]> {
    let observables: any = [];
    let subString = 'Job';


    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let url = 'urlPath/' + data[i];

      observables.push(this.http.get(url)
        .map(this.extractPath)

        //Send the "children" from each character: age, job_1, job_2, etc..
        .concatMap((data) => this.getCharactersValues(data))
        .catch(this.handleError));
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
  }

  getCharactersValues(data): Observable<String[]> {
    let observables: any = [];

    //Get Age Value
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let url = 'urlPath/' + data[i];

      if (url.includes('Age')) {
        observables.push(this.http.get(url)
          .map(this.extractValue)
          .catch(this.handleError));
      }

      //Get Jobs Endpoints
      if (url.includes('Job')) {
        let url = 'urlPath/' + data[i];
        observables.push(this.http.get(url)
          .map(this.extractPath)
          //Send the "children" from each Job: position, company, etc..
          .concatMap((data) => this.getJobsValues(data))
          .catch(this.handleError));

      }
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
  }


  getJobsValues(data): Observable<Number[]> {
    let observables: any = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let url =  'urlPath/' + data[i];
      observables.push(this.http.get(url).map(this.extractValue).catch(this.handleError));
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
  }


  private extractPath(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json().children;
    return body;
  }

  private extractValue(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json().value;
    return body;
  }


  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); 
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

When I print characterVariable I get:

```
  Json Object 
  0:  Array[5]
      0:  21 //This is the age
      1 : Array[2]
        0 : "current position" //Current job position
        1 : "current company" //Current company
      2 : Array[2]
        0 : "previous position" //Previous job position
        1 : "previous company" //Previous company       
        ....
   1:  Array[5]
      0:  32 //This is the age
      1 : Array[2]
        0 : "current position" //Current job position
        1 : "current company" //Current company
      2 : Array[2]
        0 : "previous position" //Previous job position
        1 : "previous company" //Previous company       
        ....
```

I don´t know if this is the best way to organise the data. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The next question is, where should I define that array[0][0] is the age of the first character in order to create the json Object similar to the one defined at the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: Why like this.../Characters/Character_1 instead return response value in a array

Comment: Remove the `| async` pipe from the `ngFor` next to `character` because `character` is not an `Observable`/`Promise`.

Comment: If you use {{character | JSON}} in your template, it will display the whole object piped through the JSON filter, although this is really only useful for debugging - you're going to want to use a more structured approach to displaying the object.

Comment: You could use `Observable.forkJoin` to combine multiple API calls into one response in your service

Comment: @StephenR.Smith I get Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The pipe 'JSON' could not be found . I tried to add CommonModule  in app.module.ts but it also didn´t work. I define public character: any; in my component. Should I do something else in order to see this info ? Thanks!

Comment: @Sreemat you are right. It is better to return an array of characters, as to define each character. In my case I did it that way because before getting each characters info, I need to know how many characters there are (using another endpoint). Your proposal is however more clean and accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - {{ character | json }} - should be lower case.

Comment: @0mpurdy forkJoin and concatMap do the work. But I receive an array as result, how can I build the json Object from this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Observable.forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to combine the data of many requests.

### Single Item

```js
const numbersObs = Observable.from(['1', '2', '3', '4']);
const lettersObs = Observable.from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
const booleanObs = Observable.from([true, true, false, false]);

Observable.forkJoin(numbersObs, lettersObs, booleanObs)
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log("result", result);
    this.singleResult = {
        id: result[0],
        name: result[1],
        selected: result[2]
      }
  })
```

This will create an object:

```json
{
  "id": "4",
  "name": "d",
  "selected": false
}
```

From the last emitted item of each observable.

[Live plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xrk55WJ49GzdfWdR5eWJ?p=preview)

### Array of items

If you wanted to create an array of objects from arrays returned from fork join you could do that as well (included in plunker example and code below) **This code assumes the order is correct and that all the property arrays are the same length (each item has every property)**

```js
// If you can guarantee all the results in the correct order
Observable.forkJoin(numbersObs.toArray(), lettersObs.toArray(), booleanObs.toArray())
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log("result", result);
    this.results = result[0].map((item, index) => {
      return {
        id: result[0][index],
        name: result[1][index],
        selected: result[2][index]
      }
    })
  })
```

This will create

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "a",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "b",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "c",
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "d",
    "selected": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Ahh ! So I have to map the nested arrays and assign a property to each value. It seems I don´t only have a lack of knowledge in Angular but also in basic Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: I will post lately my solution (as I am now slowly mapping the array), but it is pretty much based on your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a sample with your code, seems everything fine but:

1) Are you sure that somebody called getCharacters() and  getCharactersAge() methods on component

2) You can easily transform JSON data structure to array using map operator

3) Somebody should call unsubscribe. Below you can find an example of using async pipe - in that case unsubscribe will be called automatically on component destroy stage

A component in nutshell:

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';

    character: any;
    character$: Observable<any>;

    errorMessage: any;

    constructor(private _service: MyNewServiceService) {
      this.getCharacters();

      // Better way - with auto usubscribe
      this.character$ = this._service.getCharacters();
    }

    getCharacters() {
      // here problem - no unsubscription !
      this._service.getCharacters().subscribe(
        (characters) => {
          this.character = characters;
        },
        (error) => {
        },
        () => {
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

template:

```
    <ul>
      {{character | json}}

      <p *ngFor="let person of character">
        <span>{{person.name}}</span>
      </p>

      <p *ngFor="let person of (character$|async)">
        <span>{{person.name}}</span>
      </p>

    </ul>
```

Service stub:

```
  import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

  @Injectable()
  export class MyNewServiceService {

    constructor() {
    }

    getCharacters() {

      const x = {
        character1: {
          name: 'Name of Character 1',
          age: '21',
          jobs: {
            job1: {
              position: '',
              company: ''
            },
            job2: {
              position: '',
              company: ''
            }
          }
        },
        character2: {
          name: 'Name of Character 2',
          age: '21',
          jobs: {
            job1: {
              position: '',
              company: ''
            },
            job2: {
              position: '',
              company: ''
            }
          }
        }
      };

      // debugger
      // const z = Observable.of(false);
      return Observable.from([x]).map( (data) => {
        const result = [];
        Object.keys(data).forEach( key => {
          result.push(data[key]);
        });
        return result;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: 1) I call getCharacters and getCharactersAge in the component constructor. 3)Why does it need to unsubscribe ? Thanks

Comment: Because no one will unsubscribe it for you. It kind of "resource leak" because you subscription and observable life time will be equal to service life time.

Comment: But if your observable will be compleated it's not so critical

Comment: Ok, but the problem I´m having right now is not displaying a Json Object with ngFor, but collecting the data from multiple http calls and create what you define as "const x ".

Comment: You can use Observable.combineLatest( [ request1$, request2$, request3$ ], (combinedResults)=> { 
 const [request1Result, request2Result, request3Result] = combinedResults;   .....build object ...}) Once all request will be compleated you will get a result